# how to clone/copy a datatable with only first n columns using linq

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, datatable

I have a datatable containing over 100 columns, how ever I need to strip out all columns 
except first 11 columns.
I need to retain data of 1st 11 columns. 
I am doing it with following code

```
public DataTable validdatatable(DataTable table)
{
     DataTable dt = new DataTable();
     for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++)
     {
          DataColumn dc = new DataColumn();
          dc.ColumnName = table.Columns[i].ColumnName;
          dc.DataType = table.Columns[i].DataType;
          dt.Columns.Add(dc);
     }
     for (int i = 0; i < table.Rows.Count; i++)
     {
          object[] ob = table.Rows[i].ItemArray;
          ...
          ...
     }
     return dt;
}
```

This methods works but is too heavy on CPU and Ram.

Is there any other method with which I can proceed?

Comment: "but is too heavy on CPU and Ram." ?  I didn't realise there were any 286's left.... :)

Comment: out of memory exception is being thrown. I cant increase ram. I know why i am getting the exception because objects created in 2nd for loop are not getting freed. The server is XP with only 1 gb ram, which is always full.

Comment: Note that DataTable holds all its data in memory at once.  If you accept a DataTable and produce a DataTable result, then naïve solutions will often require the memory usage for both tables.

What is the result used for?  Where does the input come from?  Those are key pieces of information that can inform a change to the method's signature that will allow more breathing room for a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public DataTable validdatatable(DataTable table)
{
 var dt = table.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Take(11);

 return dt.CopyToDataTable();
}
```

Or Something like this. It will give you at least a way to work on it.
Note that You need to add a reference to the assembly: `System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll` then you can write your function like above.

Comment: That just gives the first 11 rows.  OP appears to want the data in the first 11 columns of each row.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.  The only difference would be instead of object[] ob = table.Rows[i].ItemArray it will just grab the first 11 columns using the index and make an array out of that (itemArray will make an array of all 100 columns).  Still doubt this will solve your memory issues if you are that tight but it's probably worth a shot.

```
var copyDt = new DataTable();
for (var i = 0; i < 11; i++)
{
    copyDt.Columns.Add(dataTable.Columns[i].ColumnName, dataTable.Columns[1].DataType);
}
copyDt.BeginLoadData();
foreach (DataRow dr in dataTable.Rows)
{
    copyDt.Rows.Add(Enumerable.Range(0, 11).Select(i => dr[i]).ToArray());
}
copyDt.EndLoadData();
```